Is combining filter and search a good idea?
I’ve been struggling to design a history log. My goal is to include a search button for quickly finding specific entries and a filter option to narrow down data based on specific criteria. My main concern is whether it's a good practice to integrate the filter into the search button or keep them separate.

Additionally, does my design seem cluttered with two buttons on the right side, along with the search bar?
Another question is whether the way I’m displaying the history log makes sense. My reference point is the history feature in Redmine: click here
Would really love to hear some thoughts!

You can combine them. Depending on the requirement of your user base. A free search field can be part of a more sophisticated filter structure.

You've not provided any reasoning behind your suggestion. Please elaborate on why you have come to this conclusion.
